# How to set Quicksand font as global font?

Tags: nuxtjs3

Below is my current configuration

```js
buildModules: ["@nuxtjs/google-fonts"],
  css: [
    "vuetify/lib/styles/main.sass",
    "@mdi/font/css/materialdesignicons.min.css",
  ],
  googleFonts: {
    families: {
      Quicksand: true,
    },
  },
```

It works when used in components like below:

```css
.test-font {
  font-family: "Quicksand", -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI",
    Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", Arial, "Noto Sans", sans-serif,
    "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol", "Noto Color Emoji";
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 5em;
}
```

But how to set it globally as default instead of using it in a css style paragraph?

Comment: Quite sure you posted that question already... Why deleting the previous one?

Comment: Sorry, I worded my problem incorrectly. I prefer to correct the sentence.

Comment: Then edit your question rather than deleting it.

Comment: My comment in your previous question is still relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74458885/how-to-add-a-font-in-my-full-nuxt-3-website/74459525#74459525